# Failed to install Potree on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic

Tags: installation, lidar, ubuntu, lastools, potree

I am trying to install Potree on my computer and I am stuck. I am following these instructions:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-software-properties git
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake g++
$ sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
$ sudo apt-get install cmake-curses-gui
$ sudo apt-get install gcc
```

LAStools:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/m-schuetz/LAStools.git
$ cd LAStools/LASzip
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
$ make
```

Potree Converter:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/potree/PotreeConverter.git
$ cd PotreeConverter
$ mkdir build && cd build  
$ sudo cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLASZIP_INCLUDE_DIRS=/home/opengeo/LAStools/LASzip/dll -DLASZIP_LIBRARY=/home/opengeo/LAStools/LASzip/build/src/liblaszip.so ..
**$ sudo make && sudo make install**
$ sudo ln -s ~/LAStools/LASzip/build/src/liblaszip.so /usr/lib
$ PotreeConverter -h
```

Anyway, I installed LAStools and I have problem with Potree. When I run command:

```
**$ sudo make && sudo make install**
```

I get:

```
Scanning dependencies of target PotreeConverter
 [  8%] Building CXX object 
PotreeConverter/CMakeFiles/PotreeConverter.dir/src/BINPointReader.cpp.o
[ 16%] Building CXX object PotreeConverter/CMakeFiles/PotreeConverter.dir/src/GridCell.cpp.o
[ 25%] Building CXX object 
 PotreeConverter/CMakeFiles/PotreeConverter.dir/src/LASPointReader.cpp.o

 /home/user/LAStools/LASzip/build/PotreeConverter/PotreeConverter/src/LASPointReader.cpp:8:10: 
  fatal error: laszip_api.h: No such file or directory
   #include "laszip_api.h"
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
   PotreeConverter/CMakeFiles/PotreeConverter.dir/build.make:110: recipe for target 
   'PotreeConverter/CMakeFiles/PotreeConverter.dir/src/LASPointReader.cpp.o' failed
   make[2]: *** [PotreeConverter/CMakeFiles/PotreeConverter.dir/src/LASPointReader.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:85: recipe for target 'PotreeConverter/CMakeFiles/PotreeConverter.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [PotreeConverter/CMakeFiles/PotreeConverter.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

But I have laszip_api.h in LAStools/LASzip/dll

I tried to manually copy it in /LAStools/LASzip/build/PotreeConverter/build but without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue at the [Github Repository](https://github.com/potree/PotreeConverter/issues/327) that threats the same problem.

The person solved the issue by running the make and make install separated without the && (AND_IF) operator:

```
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 0):

in the line :

> sudo cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
>   -DLASZIP_INCLUDE_DIRS=/home/**opengeo**/LAStools/LASzip/dll -DLASZIP_LIBRARY=/home/**opengeo**/LAStools/LASzip/build/src/liblaszip.so
>   ..

Change `opengeo` to your username